# Moving UIView with CABasicAnimations and CoreMotion

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I want to move my UIView up and down (x axis) with the accelerometer but keep it within the screen. Currently, I can't get it to move in coordination with the accelerometer. I have an NSTimer that fires every 0.05 seconds (which is how often the Accelerometer updates) and calls a method which attempts to move the UIView. How can I get the UIView to move based on the accelerometer's movement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.05 seconds is too short an interval to do any meaningful animation. Think in terms of .1 seconds or so at a minimum.

If you can't get animations to work, post your code. Also tell us if you are using Storyboards (the default) or XIB files.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to have a look at :

1. http://tech.pro/tutorial/968/iphone-tutorial-reading-the-accelerometer
2. **[iTuneU - Standford - Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550) - video 17. Camera, Core Motion, Application Lifecycle**

If you have time, Standford course on iPhone/iPad Dev are TOP !